# How to add a custom web part to a webpart page through code?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2007

I wanna how to add a custom web part to a webpart page through code? The custom web part is already deployed to the SharePoint site. It's a MOSS instance.

Answer (score 1):

To place a web part on a page you have to use the [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) which could be retrieved from the actual SPWeb object.

After creating an instance of the web part you want to add to the page, you call the [AddWebPart()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms416766.aspx) method of the web part manager and pass the web part instance as a parameter.